# Is $E(\sin Z)=\sin E(Z)$ for $Z\sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, means

Let $Z$ be a random variable of the standarized normal distribution. True or false? $E(\sin Z)=\sin (E(Z))$ ($E$ stands for the mean value).

Comments. Since $\displaystyle \sin Z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{Z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, we would just like to interchange $E$ (i.e. the integral) with the series - unfortunatelly though we are not dealing with positive rv's, in order to work with the standard Beppo Levi theorem. I am aware of the alternative version for rv's with values on $[-\infty,+\infty]$, according to which I have to check that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E\bigg(\frac{|Z|^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\bigg)$ converges. But I am stuck at the estimations of $E(|Z|^{2n+1})$ - at this point I am thinking of evaluating the integrals $\displaystyle \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|z|^{2n+1}f_Z(z)dz=2\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}z^{2n+1}f_Z(z)dz$, which seems to be a bit troubleshooting though. Am I on the right path or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you are after this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments (but of course @Ian's remark makes even this, moot).

Comment: The expected value of an odd function of a symmetric variable, if it exists, is zero. So the problem reduces to showing $E[\sin Z]$ just exists.

Comment: Also, it would not be enough to just interchange summation and expectation, because you would then need to interchange the expectation with the power, that is, you would need $E[Z^{2n+1}]=(E[Z])^{2n+1}$. This step will usually fail (whereas the first interchange will quite frequently work). In this particular case it turns out both steps work, but still, this is an unnecessarily hard way to proceed.

Comment: @Ian i see. But we come to these (1) why does the mean exist and (2) basically, I noticed after that $E(\sin Z)=0$ using the argument you wrote. Basically, I am looking both for $E(\sin Z)$ and $E(\cos Z)$ - and I hoped the above method would provide me  a systematic approach.

Comment: 1. The mean exists because $\sin$ is bounded and measurable. 2. $E[\cos(Z)]$ will be less than $1$ (why?) whereas $\cos(0)=1$. You can compute $E[\cos(Z)]$ the way that you attempted for $\sin$, the interchange will indeed turn out to be justified by dominated convergence. Alternately you can write down the integral explicitly, rewrite it using Euler's formula, and get a tractable integral (it's like a Gaussian integral with a complex variance).

Comment: @Ian got it! Thanks!

Comment: @Did thanks for the link and thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking much too hard.

$E[Z]=0$ so $\sin E[Z]=0$.  On the other hand, $Z$ has a symmetric distribution, so for any measurable function $f$, if $E[f(Z)]$ exists then so does $E[f(-Z)]$ and they are equal.  $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is bounded so $E[\sin(Z)]$ certainly exists.  Thus $E[\sin(Z)] = E[\sin(-Z)] = E[-\sin(Z)] = -E[\sin(Z)]$ because $\sin(x)$ is an odd function and $E$ is linear.  So $E[\sin(Z)]=0$.

Even more simply, we have
$$E[\sin(Z)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx.$$
The integrand is bounded in absolute value by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\,dx$, whose integral converges, so this integral converges too.  And the integrand is odd, so the integral equals 0.

Comment: thanks! Just a thing: if rv $X:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is symmetric then $f(X)$ is also symmetric for any Borel measurable function $f$? (it sounds a bit too much, without any properties on $f$, for example $f$ being even)

Comment: @NikolaosSkout: No, that's certainly not true in general.

Comment: Hm, so how do you get that $\sin Z$ and $-\sin Z$ are identically distributed on $\mathbb{R}$? (after that, all the arguments work of course)

Comment: @NikolaosSkout: I didn't actually claim that $\sin(Z)$ and $-\sin(Z)$ were identically distributed, merely that they had they had the same expected value.  But they are identically distributed: in general, if $X$ and $X'$ are identically distributed then so are $f(X)$ and $f(X')$ for any measurable function $f$.  Now $Z$ and $-Z$ are identically distributed, and since $\sin(x)$ is odd we have $-\sin(Z) = \sin(-Z)$.

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot!